# Implementing Oracle's rownum() in Apache Impala

Tags: oracle, impala

I am converting an Oracle query into Impala equivalent. I have a Oracle query like this:

```
select c1, c2 from t1 
where rownum <= (select c3 from t2 where c4 = 'Some string' and c5 = 'some string')
and c2 in (1,2,3) order by c3 asc;
```

However Impala does not support **rownum()** that I came to know while researching. Please help me in implementing this in Impala.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html#row_number), you can use row_number of Impala as it is.
Which means your query would be executed successfully if you try this way:

```
select column from table
where row_number = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, i do not think there is any system function like this. You need to calculate the column.

Comment: I do not have a compilable environment to try row_number of Impala, but I tried to explain the documentation of it, it is good to know how to use row_number() over though.

Comment: welcome... you can use https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=358102 for hive (which is similar to Impala) :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have anything like rownum in oracle. However you can create a pseudo column using `row_number() over (partition by col, order by col)` function. You need to avoid partition by clause.
You can change your sql and add a subquery to calculate rownum column like below.
Also you need to change your query so it works in impala using join instead of the way you wrote above.

```
select c1, c2, c3 from 
(select c1,c2, row_number() over (order by c1) as rownum from t1 ) t1
join (select c3 from t2 where c4 = 'Some string' and c5 = 'some string')
and c2 in (1,2,3)) t2 on
rownum<=t2.c3  
order by c3 asc;
```